# Databinding: Bind single method from listener with multiple methods

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

Yigit Boyar and George Mount members of the Android UI Toolkit team gave a [talk on databinding](https://realm.io/news/data-binding-android-boyar-mount/). In the video at 13:41 George Mount says this

> You can also do some of the weird listeners, like onTextChanged.
>   TextWatcher has three methods on it, but everybody only cares about
>   onTextChanged, right? **You can actually access just one of them if you
>   want, or all of them.**"
>
> ```
> <Button android:onTextChanged="@{handlers.textChanged}" …/>
> ```

He seemed to be saying that instead of using the usual [addTextChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)) method that looks something like this

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        //Do something
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
});
```

we could simply do this

```
<EditText 
    android:onTextChanged="@{handlers::onTextChanged}"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Handlers class

```
public class Handlers{
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

The code works in this instance, but it doesn't seem to work in other cases where the listener has multiple methods like ViewPager's [addOnPageChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#addOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)) method. For example this doesn't work

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:OnPageSelected="@{handlers::onPageSelected}"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

and the Handlers class

```
public class Handlers{
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

The project spits out this error when trying to build

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Could not resolve handlers::onPageSelected as a listener.

****\ data binding error ****
```

I'm a bit confused now because it turns out that EditText actually has an inherited [onTextChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onTextChanged(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int)) method which the databinding library can also bind `android:onTextChanged="@{handlers::onTextChanged}"` to.

So my question is that is it actually possible to bind to a single listener method and I'm missing something, or did George Mount make a mistake in his talk?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's hope that it wasn't a mistake in the talk :-)

It looks like we didn't implement it for `ViewPager`. The implementation is not too difficult. There is a trick -- you must declare a single interface for each matching method.

```
public interface OnPageScrollStateChanged {
    void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state);
}
public interface OnPageScrolled {
    void onPageScrolled(int position, float offset, int offsetPixels);
}
public interface OnPageSelected {
    void onPageSelected(int position);
}
```

Then the binding adapter should be created for the events:

```
@BindingAdapter(value = {"android:onPageScrollStateChanged",
                         "android:onPageScrolled",
                         "android:onPageSelected"}, requireAll=false)
public static void setViewPagerListeners(ViewPager view,
        final OnPageScrollStateChanged scrollStateChanged,
        final OnPageScrolled scrolled,
        final OnPageSelected selected) {
    OnPageChangeListener newListener = null;
    if (scrollStateChanged != null || scrolled != null || selected != null) {
        newListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                if (scrollStateChanged != null) {
                    scrollStateChanged.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
                }
            }
            // similar with the other two methods ...
        };
    }

    OnPageChangeListener oldListener = ListenerUtil.trackListener(view,
        newListener, R.id.viewPagerListener);
    if (oldListener != null) {
        view.removeOnPageChangeListener(oldListener);
    }
    if (newListener != null) {
        view.addOnPageChangeListener(newListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Answer straight from the horse's mouth :)

Comment: What is R.id.viewPagerListener?